# how to make only a part of screen scrollable

Tags: struts2, include

I've developed menu tabs in Tabs. jsp and included it in my Main.jsp . Now is it possible to make the Tabs not scroll in the jsp (i,e) the file that is included should not be scrolling down. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This has got nothing to do with Struts2, what you need is a floating menu which shouldnt scroll and should be fixed, there are multiple ways of doing it, one very simple but nice way can be found [here](http://www.dittocode.com/how-to-emulate-gmails-floating-menu-bar-with-jquery/)